# "Gamma Gallery" lightbox script & XAMPP Glitch

Tags: php, xampp, lightbox, image-gallery

my question is in relation to a variation of the lightbox script - [Gamma Gallery](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/06/gamma-gallery-a-responsive-image-gallery-experiment/), and [XAMPP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp). My gallery is all set, but I'd really like to convert my html files to PHP, mostly for the convenience offered by the "include_once" feature.

However, whenever I click on a gallery item & then close it, the script doesn't reset from one with a trailing ID - "index.php?id=1", back to "index.php". This completely messes up the script & no image/s can be opened until the URL is reset back to index.php. This glitch doesn't happen with ASP, but I'm on a Windows server. Everything seems to work on the server, but I'd really, reeeeally like to know if there's a fix for this XAMPP glitch, because I have a ton of images for this gallery & would like to test everything locally for now.

Just wondering if anyone's ever encountered a similar problem. If anyone could offer any clues as to what's going on or suggest some search terms, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance, this community has been very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I was using the Gamma Gallery from tympanus/codrops; In order to stop the ?id from getting in my way in the url, I just had to 'remove these 2 files from the page which deals with url and history:....history.js  and ....url.min.js

The Gallery works just fine without putting any ?id in the url...used on the profile page here: http://www.classificados.xxx/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble. The above solution of removing the history.js and url.min.js file does indeed work, though it isn't the best solution as Android mobile devices run into trouble with it.

The best way to solve this trouble is actually in gamma.js

Line 182, Change from true to false.

```
historyapi : false
```